# Google Chromecast disrupts Wifi

Tags: chromecast

I bought a Chromecast and set it up. I then proceeded to cast my first video. As soon as I cast the video, the WiFi went down. Rebooting the router did not fix it. I had to reboot my cable modem as well. I tried casting again and this time the WiFi went down after an hour or so. Has anyone run into this and know how to fix it? My router is a Belkin.

http://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/1jrav9/chromecast_interfering_with_laptops_wifi/

Comment: What does "the wifi went down" mean precisely? Did computers continue to detect the network? Could they connect to it? Were they assigned IP addresses? Also, what's your set up? Is router cable modem also routing or is just bridging?

Comment: wifi went down means computers did not recognize any network.

Comment: There is a setting in your router to enable multimedia over wifi to run better. When home I'll have a look. Backup your router settings first.

Comment: Also, are you casting from a smartphone, tablet or PC? Looks like laptop. Update drivers and Windows update.